# How can i turn this React class component into a functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, functional-programming

I'm working on implementing a braintree payment method in my react/mui app. I've found a way that works, but it's in a class component. How can I convert this info a proper functional component?

```
    const BraintreeDropInPaymentMethod = () => {
    class Store extends React.Component {
        instance;

        state = {
            clientToken: '<BRAIN TREE KEY>'
        };

        async componentDidMount() {
            const response = await fetch("server.test/client_token");
            const clientToken = await response.json();

            this.setState({
                clientToken,
            });
        }

        async buy() {
            const { nonce } = await this.instance.requestPaymentMethod();
            await fetch(`server.test/purchase/${nonce}`);
        }

        render() {
            if (!this.state.clientToken) {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <h1>Loading...</h1>
                    </div>
                );
            } else {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <DropIn
                            options={{ authorization: this.state.clientToken }}
                            onInstance={(instance) => (this.instance = instance)}
                        />
                        <Button
                            variant='contained'
                            onClick={this.buy.bind(this)}
                        >
                            Create Account
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                            variant='outlined'
                            sx={{ marginLeft: 3 }}
                            color='warning'
                            onClick={(e) => handleCancelAccountCreation(e)}
                            href='/store-front'
                        >
                            Cancel
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }
    }

    const [user, setUser] = useState({})
    const handleCancelAccountCreation = (event) => {
        setUser({})
        document.getElementById('signInBtn').hidden = false
    }

    return (
        <Store/>
    )
}
```

this is my attempt, but I'm coming up short on how I should handle `componentDidMount()`. I know how to handle `useState` in some situations, except for this one. Also, how can I handle the 'instance' section in a functional format? thanks.

```
    const BraintreeDropInPaymentMethod = () => {

    const [token, setToken] = useState('<BRAIN TREE KEY>')
    const [user, setUser] = useState({})

    const contactServer = async () => {
        const res = await fetch('server.test/client_token')
        const clientToken = await res.json()
        console.log(clientToken)
        setToken(token)
    }

    const buy = async () => {
        const { nonce } = await this.instance.requestPaymentMethod()
        await fetch(`server.test/purchase/${nonce}`)
    }

    const handleCancelAccountCreation = (event) => {
        setUser({})
        document.getElementById('signInBtn').hidden = false
    }

    const createAccountOptions = () => {
        if (!token) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>Loading...</h1>
                </div>
            ) else {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <DropIn
                            options={ authorization: {setToken})
                            onInstance={(instance) => (this.instance = instance)}
                        />
                        <Button
                            variant="contained'
                            onClick={buy}
                        >
                         Create Account
                        </Button
                            variant='outlined'
                            sx={{ marginLeft: 3 }}
                            color='warning'
                            onClick={(e) => handleCancelAccountCreation(e)}
                            href='/store-front'
                        >
                        <Button>
                            Cancel
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        }
    }

    return(
        <>
            <createAccountOptions/>
        </>
    )   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The functional equivalent of `componentDidMount()` is the [`useEffect` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

In this case you would change this:

```
    async componentDidMount() {
        const response = await fetch("server.test/client_token");
        const clientToken = await response.json();

        this.setState({
            clientToken,
        });
    }
```

Into something like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("server.test/client_token");
    const clientToken = await response.json();
    setState((old) => clientToken);
  };
```

Using the `useEffect` hook with an empty array as a dependency makes the function in it only run once as the component mounts.

Comment: thank you! that helps a lot. any guidance on how I should handle 'instance' in the class component?

Comment: @mooneyesLB I'm not entirely sure what `instance` does in your class component, maybe you can shed some light on its functionality